# Implementar filas para gerenciar a concorrência entre spiders no Scrapyd

Tags: python, aplicação-web, web-crawler, scrapy

Existe alguma maneira de o Scrapyd criar filas de spiders de forma que quando eu envie muitas spiders (com funções diferentes) eu possa privilegiar/limitar a concorrência entre elas? Hoje, todas as Spiders que eu envio executam de acordo com a ordem estipulada pelo servidor Scrapyd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, se você precisa de prioridades simples, uma opção é usar o parâmetro de prioridades do scrapyd (isso não está documentado mas [está implementado aqui](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/blob/master/scrapyd/spiderqueue.py), é basicamente uma fila de prioridades básica em cima do Sqlite).

Para usar, basta passar o argumento `priority=NUMERO` quando chamar a API [`/schedule.json`](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#schedule-json). O valor default é `0`, use um valor maior para maior prioridade.

Se você precisa de algum esquema de filas mais complexo, talvez tenha que implementar alguma solução própria. Ou então usar o [Scrapy Cloud](http://scrapinghub.com/scrapy-cloud/) da [Scrapinghub](http://scrapinghub.com) **[*]**, e estruturar o crawling usando as filas do [Hub Crawl Frontier](http://doc.scrapinghub.com/frontier.html).

**[*]** para transparência completa: trabalho na Scrapinghub